# How do I pass external application properties to springboot app in a docker container

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, application.properties

Please I have read posts that seem to address this, but I am still not able to solve my problem. I have a default application.properties in my spring boot app running inside a docker container, However I want to add external application.properties.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM tomcat:8-alpine
COPY target/demoapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/demo.war
RUN sh -c 'touch /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/demo.war'
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/demo.war", "--spring.config.location=C:/Users/650/Documents/Workplace/application.properties"]
```

I build the file with:

```
docker build . -t imagename
```

And I run the spring boot docker container with:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v C:/Users/650/Documents/Workplace/application.properties:/config/application.properties --name demosirs --link postgres-
standalone:postgres -d imagename
```

The container still doesnt locate my external application.properties, please how do I overcome this challenge ?

Answer (score 3):

You are referring to the host path in the docker `ENTRYPOINT` command. Just refer to the container specific path:

> ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/demo.war", "--spring.config.location=**/config/application.properties**"]

And, I notice, you are using files as values to the `-v` argument to `docker run`. So change that to the corresponding directory:

> -v C:/Users/650/Documents/Workplace:/config

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, but the container aint still picking up the external application.properties file.

Comment: How do you verify that the container doesn't pick it up? Do you see logs? If yes, please append them to your question.

Comment: Also, I notice, you are invoking `java -jar` on a `war` file. If the `demo.war` is built as a web archive, then it is meant to be run within the tomcat container, not as a java application. In that case you may have to invoke start-tomcat.sh or something similar. If you want to run the demo app with it's embedded container, then I guess you probably would have a self-contained executable jar in your `target` directory. You seem to be following : https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/. Notice that the executable there is `app.jar` not `war`

Comment: I can verify that the container isnt picking the properties because my database properties are inside and when the container runs, it throws errors relating to the database connection.

Comment: Furthermore, I am able to build, execute and run the demo.war file with exactly the same Dockerfile if i dont externalise the application.properties. it works well if i place my application.properties inside the project. thanks

Comment: Run `docker exec -it demosirs bash` post the `docker run` and verify whether you can `cat /config/application.properties` from within the container. Try other commands for analyzing further within the container.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this? An exported image would mean having to setup directory mappings each time. I would love to have to distribute the image only but with external configuration, without having to rebuild the image in order to change the paths.

Answer (score 2):

In your entrypoint pass another argument

`-Dspring.config.location=<your custom property file location>`

Answer (score 1):

you can try giving file path instead of the classpath.

```
 "--spring.config.location=file:${configDirectory}/application.yml"
```

You can make use of spring cloud config project.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/